# Proof of attenuation bias in multiple linear regression model

Tags: regression, bias, unbiased-estimator

Consider the case of measurement error with a single explanatory variable measured with error
\begin{equation}
y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + ... + \beta_k x^{\ast}_k + \nu
\label{equation_mesurement}
\end{equation}
where $y,x_1,x_2,..,x_{k-1}$ are observable but $x^{\ast}_k$ is not. What we observe, instead, is $x_k$.

We assume at a minimum that the model at least satisfies the first four Gauss-Markov assumptions (not necessarily homoskedasticity). Thus, $\nu$ has zero mean and is uncorrelated with $x_1,x_2,...,x_{k-1},x^{\ast}_k$. In other words $\mathbb{E}(y|x_1,x_2,...,x_{k-1},x^{\ast}_k) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + ... + \beta_k x^{\ast}_k$.

A maintained assumption is that $\nu$ is also uncorrelated with $x_k$.

The measurement error in the population is
\begin{equation}
e_k = x_k - x^{\ast}_k
\label{error2}
\end{equation}
We assume that the measurement error in the population is zero $\mathbb{E}(e_k)=0$. Since $\nu$ is assumed to be uncorrelated with $x_k$ and $x^{\ast}_k$, it will be also uncorrelated with $e_k$.

A usual assumption is that $e_k$ is uncorrelated with the explanatory variables not measured with error $x_1,x_2,...,x_{k-1}$.

Suppose we are in the classical errors-in-variables (CEV) case:
\begin{equation}
 Cov(e_k,x^{\ast}_k)=0,
 \label{assumption2}
\end{equation}

The question is how can I find the plim$(\hat{\beta}_j)$?

By following the hints of my book:

Step.1:
Write the linear projection of $x^{\ast}_k$ onto the other explanatory variables as
\begin{equation}
  x^{\ast}_k = \delta_0 + \delta_1 x_1 + ... + \delta_{k-1} x_{k-1}+ r^{\ast}_k
 \end{equation}
Because $x_k=x^{\ast}_k + e_k$, $L(x_k|1,x_1,...,x_{k-1}) = L(x_k^{\ast}|1,x_1,...,x_{k-1}) + L(e_k|1,x_1,...,x_{k-1}) = L(x_k|1,x_1,...,x_{k-1})  $

because $e_k$ has zero mean and is uncorrelated with $x_1,…, x_{k-1}$, and so
$L(e_k|1,x_1,...,x_{k-1})$.

The linear projection error, $r_k$ is
\begin{align*}
 r_k \equiv &  x_k - L(x_k | 1, x_1, ..., x_{k-1}) = x^{\ast}_k + e_k - L(x_k^{\ast}|1,x_1,...,x_{k-1})  \\
   = & [x^{\ast}_k - L(x_k^{\ast}|1,x_1,...,x_{k-1}) ] + e_k = r^{\ast}_k + e_k
\end{align*}

Step.2:
By using the two-step projection formula (can you explain this formula ?): the coefficient on $x_k$ in $L(y|1,x_1,...,x_k)$ is the coefficient in $L(y|r_k)$, say $\pi_1$, with
\begin{equation*}
 \pi_1 =  \frac{Cov(r_k,y)}{Var(r_k)} 
\end{equation*}
which I suppose, can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
\pi_1=  \frac{Cov(r^{\ast}_k + e_k,\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 +... + \beta_k x^{\ast}_k + \nu)}{Var(r^{\ast}_k + e_k)} 
\end{equation}
By assumption, $r^{\ast}_k$ is uncorrelated with $x_1,x_2,...,x_{k-1}$ and $e_k$ is uncorrelated with  $x_1,x_2,...,x_{k-1},x^{\ast}_k$. Thus
\begin{align*}
 \pi_1 = & \frac{Cov(r^{\ast}_k + e_k,\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 +... + \beta_k x^{\ast}_k + \nu)}{Var(r^{\ast}_k + e_k)} 
\end{align*}

Step.3:
Then, I suppose that since Since $Cov(e_k,x_1)=Cov(e_k,x_2)=...=Cov(e_k,x_{k-1})=Cov(e_k,x^{\ast}_k)=Cov(e_k,\nu)=0$ and $Cov(r^{\ast}_k,x_1)=Cov(r^{\ast}_k,x_2)=...=Cov(r^{\ast}_k,x_{k-1})=Cov(r^{\ast}_k,\nu)=0$, the numerator of $\pi_1$ reduces to $Cov(r^{\ast}_k,\beta_k x^{\ast}_k)=\beta_k Cov(r^{\ast}_k,x^{\ast}_k)$. Thus
\begin{equation*}
 \pi_1 = \beta_k \frac{Cov(r^{\ast}_k, x^{\ast}_k)}{Var(r^{\ast}_k + e_k)}
\end{equation*}
Since $r_k=r^{\ast}_k + e_k$, then $Cov(r^{\ast}_k,r^{\ast}_k + e_k)= Var(r^{\ast}_k)$

Step.4
Eventually,
\begin{equation}
 \text{plim} (\hat{\beta}_k) = \beta_k \left( \frac{\sigma^2_{r^{\ast}_k}}{\sigma^2_{r^{\ast}_k} + \sigma^2_{ek}} \right)
 \label{attenuation}
\end{equation}

Are my steps correct? What is the two-step projection formula? The book cites that.